# batch set button images programmatically in swift iOS

Tags: swift, image, button, set

Trying to batch update a ton of button images (~1000) that go through a large sequence of if/else statements.  All the buttons are currently sequentially named (bd1210, bd1211, bd1212...)

```
if d[nums]!.eType == "N/A" {dBtn1210.setImage(UIImage(named: "plus"), for: UIControlState())
                    bd1210.setTitle("", for: UIControlState())
```

I was hoping I could loop through them all but inserting a variable in the button name reference  like you can use with classes, ex d[nums]!.eType] where nums is string converted from an int put into a loop... but that doesn't work with the button name, error "Use of unresolved identifier".

```
let batchRef = ["1200","1201","1202", ..., "1299"] 
for temp in batchRef  {
if d[nums]!.eType == "N/A" {dBtn[temp]!.setImage(UIImage(named: "plus"), for: UIControlState())
                    bd[temp]!.setTitle("", for: UIControlState())
}
```

How can I modify the code to loop through a bunch of buttons (or images if buttons don't work) to change what image they're displaying without hand coding each button?  Approximately 1000 buttons or images and each needs to go through the same sequence of if/else (about 15 outcomes).

Thoughts and suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Quite frankly it's hard to tell what you are trying to do without posting more code. What is the `d` array? Is the size the same as the number of buttnos? What is `eType`? That said, if you have that many buttons you shouldn't worry about naming them bd1210, bd1212, and so on. Use a loop to create an array of buttons and iterate through them as needed.

Comment: Understood, d is an object, etype is a string.   var d: [String: Device] = [:] ; class Device: Equipment {
    var zImp: Double = 3
    var kva: Double = 0  ... }